# Regex string between two strings includes brakets

Tags: c#, regex

I struggle with some regex expression.

Test string is e.g.

```
Path.parent.child[0]
```

I need to extract the "parent"
I always know the start "Path" and end "child[0]" of the test string. End can also be "child[1]" or without "[]"

I try it with: `(?<=Path.).*?(?=.child[0])`
But it not find a match. I think the [] in the child string is the problem.

Comment: You have to escape the opening square bracket `(?<=Path.).*?(?=\.child\[[0-9]+])` You can also write it without the lookarounds with a capture group `Path\.(\w+)\.child\[[0-9]+]`

Comment: How I can I use it in my c# code?

Comment: See a C# example here https://regex101.com/r/Ui1FFR/1/codegen?language=csharp

Comment: Why are there no dots in your Regex?

Comment: string my Path = "Path" , string myChild="child[0]" . And then I like to put it in my expression like var results = regex.match(testString,$"{myPath}\.(w+)\.{myChild}\[[0-9]+])

Answer (score 0):

A regex which might work is `^[^.]*\.(.*)\.[^.]*\[?\d?\]?$`

- `^` beginning of the line
- `[^.]*` anything except a dot
- `\.` a literal dot
- `(.*)` anything, captured as a group
- `\.` a literal dot again
- `[^.]*` anything except a dot
- `\[?\d?\]?` optional brackets and index. Could be `(\[\d\])?` if you don't mind another group.
- `$` end of the line

Check it on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AKdpLm/1)

But, if you always know the start and the end, you could switch to a non-Regex approach:

```
var start = "Path";
var end = "child[0]";
var s = start+".parent."+end;
// +1 for the first dot, -2 for two dots
var extracted = s.Substring(start.Length+1, s.Length-start.Length-end.Length-2);
Console.WriteLine(extracted);
```

Comment: Or even `.Split('.')[1]`

Comment: @CaiusJard: yes, if there's no more dot inside the `parent` thing

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I think your non regex approach is what I looking for.

Comment: Ah not so easy I have a list with som strings and what I want is to find the one depending on "start" and "end" so t thought I loop through all of them and try to match using regex. To put the start und end part of the string in the pattern.

Comment: If regex match I extract the middle of the string and can build it completely. Then can find the index of the string in the list

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused. You have multiple starts and multiple endings but you don't know which start and which end is in the string?

Comment: I have a list of string e.g "className.nestedClassName.propertyName",className.nestedClassName.propertyName[0]",className.nestedClassName.propertyName[1]" the target is to find the index auf the string. But I only got the start and end of the string and not the nested class names. Maybe I can try the to find the correct one by string.endwith

Comment: So you need the number `start.Length+1`? That's the index where "nestedClassName" starts.